# Convert gibberish charcters to meaningful ones

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-8

I have a file which contains the Spanish letter á but it shows an Arabic letter ﻢ. I tried these codes:

```
string s = File.ReadAllText("source.txt",Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt", false, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"));
```

or

```
byte[] input = File.ReadAllBytes("source.txt").ToArray();
File.WriteAllText("outut.txt", input, Encoding.Default);
```

Comment: Which encoding does the file use?

Comment: Unfortunately, ANSI

Comment: `ANSI` is a misnomer. I'd guess that `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" -v *CP` yields `ACP REG_SZ 1256`? And 1256 means `windows-1256` encoding i.e. Arabic (Windows)…